# How can I use an F# discriminated union type as a TestCase attribute parameter?

Tags: f#

I am trying to test that the return result from an F# function matches an expected discriminated union case. I am using NUnit to create the tests and it does not like the discriminated union type as a `TestCase` parameter. The following test case fails to compile:

```
[<TestCase("RF000123", Iccm.CallType.Request)>]
let ``callTypeFromCallNumber returns expected call type``
    callNumber callType =
    test <@ Iccm.callTypeFromCallNumber callNumber = callType @>
```

I expect that this is a limitation of NUnit but I am not completely sure. I have an idea to work around this which I will post as my answer but a more elegant solution will be nice.

How can I use a discriminated union case as a test case attribute parameter?

Comment: http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2012/05/first-class-tests-in-mbunit.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a limitation of NUnit, but of the F# language (as well as C# and VB): You can only put *constants* into attributes, but not objects. Discriminated Unions compile to objects in IL, so you can't put them into attributes.

You *can* put enums into attributes, though, since they're constants (they're numbers at run-time).

From the example in the OP, it looks like the `CallType` Discriminated Union has no associated data, so you could consider changing the design to [an enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233216) instead:

```
type CallType =
    | Request = 0
    | Incident = 1
    | ChangeManagement = 2
    | Unknown = 3
```

You should realise, though, that that makes `CallType` an enum; it's no longer a Discriminated Union. It should enable you to use the values in attributes, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my workaround to the problem. It works just fine although I find it a little bit make shift. I just use strings in place of the types and then pattern match to convert to the actual type in the assertion.

```
[<TestCase("RF000123", "Request")>]
[<TestCase("IM000123", "Incident")>]
[<TestCase("CM000123", "ChangeManagement")>]
[<TestCase("AR000123", "Unknown")>]
let ``callTypeFromCallNumber returns expected call type``
    callNumber callType =
    test <@ Iccm.callTypeFromCallNumber callNumber = match callType with
                                                     | "Request" -> Iccm.CallType.Request 
                                                     | "Incident" -> Iccm.CallType.Incident
                                                     | "ChangeManagement" -> Iccm.CallType.ChangeManagement
                                                     | _ -> Iccm.CallType.Unknown @>
```